# Coin tossing problem in general.

Tags: probability

Question: A coin is tossed $2n$ times and the sequence of head and tails are recorded, what is the probability that an equal number of heads and tails occur?

Comment: Have you heard of a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?  Also, is the coin being flipped fair and has equal probability of landing on heads as it does tails?

Answer (score 3):

If a coin is tossed $m$ times with probability of heads for each flip as $p$ and probability of tails $(1-p)$, with $m\in \Bbb N$ and $0\leq p\leq 1$, then the probability of having exactly $k$ heads total will be:

$$Pr(\text{exactly}~k~\text{heads})=\binom{m}{k}p^k(1-p)^{m-k}$$

---

In your case, how many times are we flipping the coin?  Is the coin fair?  What is the probability of flipping a head in a single flip?  How many times are we hoping to flip heads?  What then is the probability?

I.e., what plays the role of $m$? of $p$? of $k$?  What does the binomial distribution then imply about the probability?